# ext and code block's meaning in the gradle file

Tags: groovy, gradle

```
ext {
    springVersion = "3.1.0.RELEASE"
    emailNotification = "build@master.org"
}
```

Above code is the snippet of build.gradle

I understand that call ext method with { } closure parameter.
it's right?
So I think gradle is accessing springVersion and emailNotification.
I'm gonna verify my assumption with below code

```
def ext(data) {
    println data.springVersion
}

ext {
    springVersion = "3.1.0.RELEASE"
    emailNotification = "build@master.org"
}
```

but run that code
below Error occured.

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: springVersion for class: Test
```

do you explain ext and code block specifically?

Comment: How are you calling the method ext()? Could you paste the full gradle file please?

Answer (score 117):

`ext` is shorthand for `project.ext`, and is used to define *extra properties* for the `project` object. (It's also possible to define extra properties for many other objects.) When reading an extra property, the `ext.` is omitted (e.g. `println project.springVersion` or `println springVersion`). The same works from within methods. It does not make sense to declare a method named `ext`.

Comment: Hi,peter.Do you which grammar does ext involved in groovy?Or it is only in grade grammar?@Peter Niederwieser

Comment: I would be great if some one can point me where can I find documentation on the use of "ext block", tks.

Comment: @GreenLake4964
https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtraPropertiesExtension.html

Answer (score 13):

Here is the explanation for why the sample code in the question produces an error.

In the code:

```
ext {
    springVersion = "3.1.0.RELEASE"
    emailNotification = "build@master.org"
}
```

Does not pass to the function "ext" an object that has the springVersion and emailNotification properties. The curly braces don't mean a POJO but a closure.
This is why the "ext" function complains it can't get to the properties.

The idea with passing such a closure, known as a configuration closure, is that the receiving function will:

1. Modify the delegate property of the closure to point to an object that the closure properties/methods should act on.
2. execute the closure()

Thus the closure executes and when it refers to methods / properties these will be executed on the object to be configured.

Thus, the following modification to your code will make it work:

```
class DataObject {
   String springVersion;
   String emailNotification;
}

def ext(closure) {  
    def data = new DataObject() // This is the object to configure.
    closure.delegate = data;
    // need this resolve strategy for properties or they just get
    // created in the closure instead of being delegated to the object
    // to be configured. For methods you don't need this as the default
    // strategy is usually fine.
    closure.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST 
    closure() // execute the configuration closure
    println data.springVersion
}

ext {
    springVersion = "3.1.0.RELEASE"
    emailNotification = "build@master.org"
}
```

​
Hope this helps. Groovy closures get some time getting used to...

Answer (score 3):

It's the overriding of get() and set() by `ExtraPropertiesExtension` that is the key to making the configuration syntax for never before defined properties work.

```
class DataObject {
    HashMap<String, Object> props = new HashMap<String, Object>()

    Object get(String name) {
        return props.get(name)
    }

    void set(String name, @Nullable Object value) {
        props.put(name, value)
    }
}

def myExtInstance = new DataObject()

def myExt = { Closure closure ->
    def data = myExtInstance
    closure.delegate = data;
    // need this resolve strategy for properties or they just get
    // created in the closure instead of being delegated to the object
    // to be configured. For methods you don't need this as the default
    // strategy is usually fine.
    closure.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
    closure() // execute the configuration closure
    println data.springVersion
}

myExt {
    springVersion = "3.1.0.RELEASE"
    emailNotification = "build@master.org"
}

println "myExtInstance.springVersion" + myExtInstance.springVersion
```

See [ExtraPropertiesExtension docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtraPropertiesExtension.html)

Comment: You don't need the `myExt` method in this example, like `ext` is the instance of the `ExtraPropertiesExtension` too.